# wordpress with dropbox folder

Tags: wordpress, dropbox

I'm working on WordPress theme actually my first WordPress theme.
with underscores_s
which is also one of the first things I've ever programmed / coded
the theme is actually almost done (hard work) but I would like a site where I can show the contents of a dropbox folder.
I had planned to create a dropbox account with a shared folder to my private dropbox account. and use the new account with the app key to show the content. or something else but I have no idea how or where to start

Can somone help possibly with some code? :)

I know CSS and HTML and starting to understand PHP.

Answer (score 0):

To access data from a Dropbox account, you'd want to use the Dropbox PHP API.

Here's a tutorial for using it: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/php
and the documentation: http://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-php/api-docs/v1.1.x/

Comment: I had actually found this site https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/php
and read it. but are still not sure where i should paste the different code snippet

Comment: The best way to approach it would probably be to build this functionality into a Wordpress plugin. https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin